# Loop through List of Objects that contain a true Boolean field value using Java 8 Optional<T>, Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have been advised **NOT** to use `.anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(true))` by my colleagues. Reason being, it's not Null-Safe. They suggested that I should use `Optional<Boolean>` instead.

I have a List of Accounts, I want to return a `true` Boolean value only if when an account has an active loan outstanding, otherwise false.

```
@Data
public class Account {
    private String accountNumber;
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Boolean activeLoan;
    private String accountReference;
    private Double balance;
    private String status;

    public Boolean hasActiveLoan() {
        return activeLoan;
    }
}
```

In other words, only when `hasActiveLoan()` is equal to **true**.

Below is my proposed solution:

```
 Boolean checkActiveLoanRule(List<Account> accounts) {

         Optional<Boolean> loanAccountExists = Optional.of(accounts.stream()
                .map(Account::hasActiveLoanAccount)
                .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(true)));

         return loanAccountExists.equals(Optional.of(true));
     }
```

Can this be refactored to be improved somehow? Any alternative ideas?

& Most importantly, is such a solution thread-safe?

Comment: *What*? `anyMatch` is not null-safe in what way? You do see it returns a `boolean` - it **cannot** return `null`. Or are you talking about some other null-safety? Your code is faaaar to complex for the simple task it is doing. There is no need for optionals whatsoever.

Comment: @luk2302 I think you misunderstand `boolean` and `Boolean`.

Comment: Maybe if `Account::isActiveLoanAccount` returns `null` the `Predicate` will throw a `NullPointerException`, Anyway, having a class atribute being null is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: @Nathan I think you misunderstood my point.

Comment: And btw please fix the names you are using - accounts vs. requiredQueuesInput and activeLoanAccount vs. activeLoan.

Comment: @luk2302 `.anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(true)));` will take an element of the map and call `equals(true)` on it. If the element is `null`, this will throw a NPE.

Comment: @Nathan point taken, I was talking about the return value, you were talking about the argument.

Comment: Why not have your `checkActiveLoanRule()` method just have this `return accounts.stream().anyMatch(Account::hasActiveLoan);` ? Wouldn't that work ?  W.r.t threadsafety, I guess you should be fine as long as the same `requiredQueueInput` is not being shared by another thread which updates it, because in that case you will perhaps see a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Thank you friends for helping out. I have already fixed the mismatch of variable-names of 'accounts' . thank you luk2302 Anthony Raymond  Nathan.

Comment: So is the method `hasActiveLoan` or `isActiveLoanAccount`?

Comment: @Nathan No it will not.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you for identifying that mismatch in variable names. I have corrected it accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way is

```
boolean checkActiveLoanRule(List<Account> requiredQueuesInput) {
    return requiredQueuesInput.stream().anyMatch(Account::hasActiveLoan);     
}
```

You *can* change the return type to `Boolean` which I would advise against but it is your choice.

*If*  you are worried that `isActiveLoanAccount` returns `null` then you have a bigger problem. Methods should not ever return null but either always return a non-null actual value or `Optional<Something>`. That means that `hasActiveLoan` should take care of the `null`-check being:

```
public Boolean hasActiveLoan() { // I would prefer a boolean here
    return activeLoan == null ? false : activeLoan; // or Boolean.FALSE
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your colleagues are wrong. `Predicate.isEqual()` is null safe. You can verify by reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-), running a [test](http://ideone.com/VtkvN4), or checking the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/function/Predicate.java#Predicate.isEqual%28java.lang.Object%29).

As for [`Stream.anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), that returns a primitive `boolean`, which can't be null to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
accounts.stream()
        .anyMatch(account -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(account.hasActiveLoan())));
```

Comment: Or `.map(Account::isActiveLoanAccount).anyMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals)`

Answer (score 2):

There's no NPE here if you want optionals

```
accounts
   .stream()
   .anyMatch(account ->
            Optional.ofNullable(account.hasActiveLoan()).orElse(false));
```

But better to update `hasActiveLoan` method not to get NPE at all:

```
public Boolean hasActiveLoan() { 
    return Optional.ofNullable(activeLoan).orElse(false);
}
```